# Highcharts react official library not playing nicely with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I set up a sample project to use Highcharts and the official [Highcharts react wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) and it works fine, but when I try to use it with Typescript, I get the following error:

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

This is the code after I updated it to Typescript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    title: {
        text: 'Sample chart',
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 2, 3],
        },
    ],
};

export const UsingHighchartsOfficialVersion = () => (
    <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
    </div>
);
```

Any idea why using Typescript is causing this issue when it works fine in JS?

Comment: Hi @NikZB, The TypeScript declarations was added in `highcharts-react-offcial` v2.1. Please test the new version and let me know if your problem has been resolved.

Comment: @ppotaczek I got it to work now, but not the way it is shown in the README for the repo. I used:
`import * as HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';`
and then
`<HighchartsReact.default highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />`

The typescript type definitions helped me see that I could use the `default` member by showing it to me in VSCode autocomplete feature, so thanks for adding the types!